# Use Windows Live ID, but login with a different password

Tags: windows-8

Is it possible to keep my account linked to my Windows Live ID, but use a different password for logging on to my computer?

I know I can set up a PIN or a picture password for logging in locally, and those obviously aren't required for signing into my Live account on other devices (my Xbox, for example).

I don't want to set up a PIN or picture password, but I would like a password separate from my Live ID.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not change your Live ID password to be what you want to use on your windows-8 system?

Comment: My Live ID password is easy to type on an Xbox or a phone, but not so easy to type on a keyboard. I could come up with a new one, but then I'd also have to change it on my other devices. If there's no other solution, that's definitely what I'll do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to say 'NO' it's not possible.

To me any attempt to uncouple the password on the two locations would defy the logic of logging on with a Live ID account / password.

Also, if you succeeded, what would happen if you logged on at a different machine?

Comment: Presumably I would be similarly given the option of changing my password locally. If I set a PIN on this machine with my Live ID, what happens if I log in on another machine? I know I'm thinking of this more as linking my Live ID to a local account whereas the reality is that I am logging in as my Live ID, but I'm hoping there is a way to make it more link-like.

Comment: If security is not a problem, (I have a desktop at home and no teenagers), you could logon automatically without typing the password at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was also disappointed, because my password is long and complex, is a pain to type.

I fixed the problem using a fingerprint reader. Just press the finger on it and you login without pressing any other key.

Some laptops, like mine, have the fingerprint reader. I never used it before, but now I find it very useful

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to use a different password to log in to your Microsoft account and Windows Live account. This trick is unbelievable but it works. Follow these steps:

1. First of all, change your Live ID password to a simple one that you can type easily on a keyboard, then use this password to log on to your Windows 8 system.
2. Next, change your Live ID password to a strong one via https://login.live.com/.
3. Now you can log in to Windows 8 using a simple password, while logging into Windows Live account online using a strong password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Almost. Sort of. I think.

What you can do is create a local computer account, and then *link* it to your Microsoft account. Since these are two separate accounts, they have separate passwords, but you get all the benefits of logging into your computer with a Microsoft account - App store, cloud services, settings syncing, etc.

Different websites all describe the process slightly differently, and all are a little vague, but basically, you want to go into "PC Settings", go into the "Accounts" or "Users" section, and look at your (local) computer account. There should be an option there to connect a Microsoft account. This method works even for corporate domain accounts, which always have to have their own separate passwords.